# How to edit Prompt Values

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

In SAP BO 4.1 Client Tool, do we have any option to edit prompt values?
For example : I have an ID values from Database in the following format – ABC34526

But I need the ID Values to be displayed in the Prompt List as 34526 alone. I don’t want that to be changed in the database level.

Can anyone please suggest me the solution.

Regards
Riya

Answer (score 0):

You can do that at universe level by using sql functions.